# Internet sharing on Macos Ventura 13.04 broken won't give out DHCP leases

Tags: macos, network, wifi, internet-sharing

I am trying to share my wifi interface with the connected external ethernet port on macbook, after a reboot the connected device on the ethernet port does not get any ip-address, I have looked around some threads and found that I am facing the same issue where bootpd does not start automatically, but when I started it manually it does not work either. Not sure how to debug this, this is very annoying that a simple feature like internet sharing does not work on macos.

```
------------ Before unloading and reloading bootps ------------
aravind.datla@~{aravind.datla}:» sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/bootps.plist
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/bootps.plist: service already loaded
Load failed: 17: File exists

aravind.datla@~{aravind.datla}:» sudo launchctl list | grep -i boot
Password:
Sorry, try again.
Password:
-   0   com.apple.mdmclient.daemon.runatboot
-   0   com.apple.bootpd
576 0   com.apple.bootinstalld

------------ After unloading and reloading bootps ------------

aravind.datla@~{aravind.datla}:» sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/bootps.plist
aravind.datla@~{aravind.datla}:» sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/bootps.plist 

aravind.datla@~{aravind.datla}:» sudo launchctl list | grep -i boot
Password:
-   0   com.apple.mdmclient.daemon.runatboot
-   0   com.apple.bootpd
576 0   com.apple.bootinstalld

------------- Connected device en7, A bridge100 is automatically created -------------
aravind.datla@~{aravind.datla}:» ifconfig 
en7: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=404<VLAN_MTU,CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 8c:ae:4c:eb:de:54 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: inactive
bridge100: flags=8a63<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,ALLMULTI,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM>
    ether be:d0:74:60:d6:64 
    inet 192.168.2.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.2.255
    inet6 fe80::bcd0:74ff:fe60:d664%bridge100 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x16 
    inet6 fd5d:439c:cdd:79df:890:ba3a:ea3a:49b prefixlen 64 autoconf secured 
    Configuration:
        id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
        maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
        root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
        ipfilter disabled flags 0x0
    member: en7 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 21 priority 0 path cost 0
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: <unknown type>
    status: inactive
```

```
-------------- log stream --info --debug output -------------------
2023-05-30 10:47:54.720776-0500 0xa9e3     Debug       0x0                  338    0    configd: [com.apple.SystemConfiguration:SCDynamicStore] copy    : 167179 : State:/Network/Interface/en7/Link
2023-05-30 10:47:54.721127-0500 0xa9e3     Debug       0x0                  338    0    configd: [com.apple.SystemConfiguration:SCDynamicStore] copy    : 132231 : State:/Network/Interface/en7/Link
2023-05-30 10:47:57.643589-0500 0xdf0      Default     0x0                  338    0    configd: (IPConfiguration) [com.apple.IPConfiguration:Server] DHCP en7: ARP router: No leases to query for
2023-05-30 10:47:57.643724-0500 0xdf0      Info        0x0                  338    0    configd: (IPConfiguration) [com.apple.IPConfiguration:Server] DHCP en7: symptom failure already reported
2023-05-30 10:47:57.644864-0500 0xdf0      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: bpf0 attached to en7
2023-05-30 10:47:57.645072-0500 0xdf0      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: bpf0 closed and detached from en7 fcount 0 dcount 0
2023-05-30 10:47:57.645222-0500 0xdf0      Default     0x0                  338    0    configd: (IPConfiguration) [com.apple.IPConfiguration:Server] DHCP en7: INIT waiting at 60 for 8.688059
2023-05-30 10:48:06.338526-0500 0xdf0      Default     0x0                  338    0    configd: (IPConfiguration) [com.apple.IPConfiguration:Server] DHCP en7: ARP router: No leases to query for
2023-05-30 10:48:06.338728-0500 0xdf0      Info        0x0                  338    0    configd: (IPConfiguration) [com.apple.IPConfiguration:Server] DHCP en7: symptom failure already reported
2023-05-30 10:48:06.338811-0500 0xdf0      Debug       0x0                  338    0    configd: (IPConfiguration) [com.apple.IPConfiguration:Server] bootp_client_close_socket(en7): refcount 0
2023-05-30 10:48:06.338860-0500 0xdf0      Debug       0x0                  338    0    configd: (IPConfiguration) [com.apple.IPConfiguration:Server] bootp_client_close_socket(): scheduling delayed close
2023-05-30 10:48:06.341868-0500 0xdf0      Default     0x0                  338    0    configd: (IPConfiguration) [com.apple.IPConfiguration:Server] LINKLOCAL en7: publish success { IPv4 }
2023-05-30 10:48:06.341946-0500 0xdf0      Default     0x0                  338    0    configd: (IPConfiguration) [com.apple.IPConfiguration:Server] DHCP en7: status = 'no server'
2023-05-30 10:48:06.343312-0500 0xdf0      Info        0x0                  338    0    configd: (IPConfiguration) [com.apple.IPConfiguration:Server] DHCP en7: not busy
2023-05-30 10:48:06.343378-0500 0xdf0      Info        0x0                  338    0    configd: (IPConfiguration) [com.apple.IPConfiguration:Server] en7: not busy
2023-05-30 10:48:06.345616-0500 0xa9dd     Debug       0x0                  338    0    configd: [com.apple.SystemConfiguration:SCDynamicStore] *remove : 42243 : State:/Network/Interface/en7/IPConfigurationBusy
2023-05-30 10:48:06.345643-0500 0xa9dd     Debug       0x0                  338    0    configd: [com.apple.SystemConfiguration:SCDynamicStore] *remove : 42243 : State:/Network/Interface/en7/ActiveDuringSleepSupported
2023-05-30 10:48:07.343027-0500 0xdf0      Debug       0x0                  338    0    configd: (IPConfiguration) [com.apple.IPConfiguration:Server] bootp_session_delayed_close(): closing bootp socket 26
```

Comment: What if you issue the command `sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/bootps.plist`.  To check if it’s running, issue the command `sudo launchctl list | grep -i boot`. If you see a zero in the second column it should be running.  Let me know your results.  Next, get your client machine to renew the IP (unplug the Ethernet cable is one way) Do you get an IP?

Comment: Hi @Allan, I really appreciate you looking into this, I have updated my post with the command output, I do not see bootp being started, I did restarted the client, and even connected a different client. I am seeing the same no bootp is running what so ever.

Comment: Based on that output, it’s running. See if you get an IP assigned

Comment: Hi @Allan, I do not see the ip address being assigned, I even did a wireshark capture, I can see the DHCP DISCOVER requests from the client, but no DHCP offer from the MAC. Also is there any other logs I can capture/provide?

Comment: I have updated my post with the out of the `log stream`, hope it helps to verify what's missing.

Comment: Can you post the contents of `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.bootps.plist`. You can post it to pastebin or similar as to not make the question too long.  If you’re not seeing an offer from the server, then it’s not responding for some reason.  Let’s look at how Apple configured it.

Comment: Hi @Allan, here is the link for the pastebin --> https://pastebin.com/LXhf8J8j

Comment: First key says “Disabled” = “true”.  Let’s try changing that to “false” or removing altogether.

Comment: @Allen, I tried editing the file as sudo, but it would not allow me, I am sorry, I am a newbie to mac configuration, Is there a command to try, I tried the below `sudo defaults write /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/bootps.plist Disabled false` it did not work as well. I searched around none of the methods worked on  macos ventura.

Comment: Sorry… I keep forgetting about this protected system partition.  You may have to unload this one, duplicate it, but to `/Library/LaunchDaemons` (not `/System/Lib…`) and load it there.  It’s a total hack, but I can’t test at the moment (on an iPad)

Comment: Hi @Allen, I have followed your instructions, that did not help. Any other logs I can provide?
Duplicated the file to /Library/LaunchDaemons/bootps.plist and changes the key to false, then loaded this new file using launchctl. Also let me know if you want to move the discussion into a chat.

Comment: Let me do a little research on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error and searching through lot of github issues, this thread helped me fix the issue:
https://github.com/canonical/multipass/issues/2387#issuecomment-1573043587

commands that worked for me.

```
/usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw --add /usr/libexec/bootpd
/usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw --unblock /usr/libexec/bootpd
```

For me I have run the below command after every boot on the macbook, not sure why: but I can live with it for now.

```
/usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw --unblock /usr/libexec/bootpd
```

Thank you @Allan for looking into this.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Updated my answer to contain the resolution steps.

Comment: I lost internet sharing ability (due to DHCP not handling new leases) and tried the above but didn't get far.. but the solution suggested [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/79496/159704) did the trick.